# Somar inputs com IDs diferentes javascript

Tags: php, javascript

Estou com um probleminha que já me tirou do sério.

No codigo abaixo:

```html
<table width="739" border="0">
  <tr id="b1">
    <td width="144"><input name="valor1[1]" id="valor1[1]" type="number"/></td>
    <td width="144"><input name="valor2[1]" id="valor2[1]"type="number"/></td>
    <td width="144"><input name="valor3[1]" id="valor3[1]"type="number"/></td>
    <td width="144"><input name="valor4[1]" id="valor4[1]" type="number"/></td>
    <td width="141"><input name="resultado[1]" id="resultado[1]" type="number"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="b2">
    <td><input name="valor1[2]" id="valor1[2]" type="number"/></td>
    <td><input name="valor2[2]" id="valor2[2]"type="number"/></td>
    <td><input name="valor3[2]" id="valor3[2]"type="number"/></td>
    <td><input name="valor4[2]" id="valor4[2]" type="number"/></td>
    <td><input name="resultado[2]" id="resultado[2]" type="number"/></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Eu precisava que ao digitar valores nos inputs, ele somasse no resultado, mas que a soma acontecesse somente na linha. Como podem ver, os inputs possuem id's diferentes. É só um exemplo do que eu preciso.
Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: pode usar um mesmo nome ("linha1" por exemplo), pegar todos os inputs com o mesmo nome e somar

Comment: Você teria um exemplo?

Comment: procure por `getElementsByName`, deve ter perguntas aqui mesmo no site :)

Comment: Eu até achei algo a respeito, mas no código abaixo, ele exemplifica informando a id. No  caso a id é dinamica. Eu precisava pegar somente as informações da ID informada. var lisPrimeiraLista = uls[0].getElementsByTagName("li"); Como eu faço pra não informar a ID em uls[0] e pegar ela dinamicamente?

Comment: como eu disse, tente usar `getElementsByName` assim pode pegar todos os inputs com o mesmo nome, não é preciso de id

Comment: Por favor clique em [edit] e deixe mais claro o que quer. Quando vc diz "somente na linha", quer dizer que quer pegar todos os inputs de um `tr` que são "valueX" e colocar o resultado no input "resultado" do mesmo `tr`? Ou quer somar todos os inputs (e colocar o resultado onde)?

Comment: **Se** for pra somar tudo do mesmo `tr`, poderia primeiro pegar o `tr` desejado (exemplo: `var tr = document.querySelector('#b1');`) e depois pegar somente os inputs que estão dentro dele com `var inputs = tr.querySelectorAll('input[name^="valor"]')` (pega aqueles cujo `name` começa com "valor"). Depois faça um `for` nesses inputs somando os seus valores

Comment: Ricardo Pontual, quero pegar input1[1], somar mais input2[1] e imprimir o resultado em resultado1.

Comment: hkotsubo, vou tentar fazer aqui.

Answer (score -2):

voce pode fazer isso usando classes nos seus inputs como forma de localizar seus valores e adicionar um listener na div principal como no exemplo abaixo

```
<table width="739" border="0">
    <tr id="b2" onkeyup="soma(1)">
    <td><input class="somaCampos1" type="number"/></td>
    <td><input class="somaCampos1" type="number"/></td>
    <td><input class="somaCampos1" type="number"/></td>
    <td><input class="somaCampos1" type="number"/></td>
    <td><input id="resultado1" type="number"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="b2" onkeyup="soma(2)">
    <td><input class="somaCampos2" type="number"/></td>
    <td><input class="somaCampos2" type="number"/></td>
    <td><input class="somaCampos2" type="number"/></td>
    <td><input class="somaCampos2" type="number"/></td>
    <td><input id="resultado2" type="number"/></td>
  </tr>
</table>


<script>
function soma(indiceIdentifica){
let campoSoma = document.getElementsByClassName('somaCampos'+indiceIdentifica)
let total = 0
  for(let i = 0; i < campoSoma.length;i++){
    total = total + parseInt(campoSoma[i].value)
  }
  
 document.getElementsById('resultado'+indiceIdentifica).value = total
}
</script>
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Não entendi. Qual parte não ficou clara?

Comment: cezar c.a, peguei seu código do jeito que postou, e não funcionou. Estou analisando aqui pra ver onde não esta dando certo. Mas entendi a logica, só não entendi por que não esta funcionando.

Answer (score -3):

```js
    <script>
function soma(indiceIdentifica){
let campoSoma = document.getElementsByClassName('somaCampos'+indiceIdentifica)
console.log(campoSoma)
let total = 0
  for(let i = 0; i < campoSoma.length;i++){
    total = total + +campoSoma[i].value // Apenas adicionando um + antes da string já converte ela para int
    console.log(total, campoSoma[i])
  }
  
 document.getElementById('resultado'+indiceIdentifica).value = total // não é getElementsById mas sim getElementById
}
</script>
```

Comment: Evite agradecer e cumprimentar nas publicações pois aqui no [pt.so] são considerados ruído de comunicação.  Veja [Que tipo de comportamento é esperado dos usuários?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior), [Saudações e Agradecimentos](http://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/846/137387) e [Como se portar ao perguntar/responder?](http://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/38/137387)